# Datenum error when midnight is 0

Tags: matlab, date

I have data of time in the following format:

```
    2340
    2350
       0
      10
      20
      30
```

I am using datenum to be able to plot it (I have also a vectotr with the date) but when the time is "0" I get an error from the datenum. If I change manually the 0 for 000 it works, but I have a lot of data and I will like it to do this automatically. Any ideas?
The time format I am using is 'HHMM'
thanks!

Comment: When you say "2340 2350 0 10 20 30" could you be more explicit what each number is supposed to represent?

Comment: It would also help if you posted a small example of code which shows what exactly you are running that is causing a problem.

Comment: You reformated, but you didn't mention what each number is supposed to represent.  In your example, is each number the hour without padding (i.e. 2350 is 1150 pm and 10 is 1210 am?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a char array, you can convert all spaces to 0s, then run `datenum`:

```
xstr(xstr==' ') = '0';
xtime = datenum(xstr,'HHMM')
```

If the data is a cell array of strings you can convert it to char array and do the same:

```
xstr = strjust(char(xcell),'right');
%# continue as above
```